# Opening LispBox in a current emacs session

Tags: emacs, lisp

So i am starting to learn lisp with emacs and was wondering if there is a way to open up lispbox in a current emacs session with something like mx-lispbox or something. Is there anyway to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lispbox is (almost) just Emacs 23.2 with a bundled Lisp-and-Slime package.

If you already have an emacs installation that you like and want to reuse the lispbox bits, I think you can just add something like this to your `.emacs` (I'm not 100% sure because I only just looked at this myself):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "path-to-the-slime-directory-in-lispbox")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "path-to-the-ccl-exe-in-lispbox")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

And then start SLIME with `M-x slime`

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the [Lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) Emacs package, you should have slime already configured. So you should be able to start a new Lisp REPL with `M-x slime`.

Comment: how do you install slime in windows if there is way?

Comment: I don't know, I do my lisp work on Linux. It looks like the details should be handled by the lispbox package automatically - if you download and install lispbox from the link in my answer, it's supposed to have lisp, emacs and slime all set up for you. If that doesn't work, check the development mailing list on that page.